# Unity Android Build Error: > Illegal char <?> at index 7: ..\..\l?brary_man?fest\release\AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build, sdk, windows-10

I want to build my Unity project for Android. I use windows 10 Home Single Language unfortunately, I use it Turkish. I couldn't find any way to make display language English. As my research, that error occurs due to system language. Ref.: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/issues/1106

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile'.
>
> > Illegal char  at index 7: ....\l?brary_man?fest\release\AndroidManifest.xml

Any idea how can I solve that issue?

Comment: which is the name of your project/solution?

Comment: the paths unity uses cannot use any form of non a-z type letters.  Just make sure all aspects are installed in folders that dont break those rules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have talked to Unity support about this issue and they said it is a problem on gradle side and recommended me to switch my OS language to English, which solved the issue. You can do it on "All Settings > Time & Language > Language > Windows Display Language" to English. I also recommend changing Regional Format on Region tab to Turkey after language switch. I hope this will help you too.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I'll mark this as accepted answer but I'll add something for people who will buy a new device w/ W10 Single Lang. (Guys select Eng at first setup!) It wasn't that easy to change language on W10 Home Single Language Edition. You can't just change the language from settings. There is no factory reset option, too. What I did was a clean installation using the media creation tool. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10 It deletes EVERYTHING and you can select English while re-installing Windows. But! You need to install all the drivers back!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, If you have the Windows 10 Single Language like me, you need to reinstall the whole OS and change OS language to English

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the Android Gradle Plugin. This issue will be fixed in 2020.1 but for people using 2019.3 or older and can't change their system language, here is a workaround I am using:

- Install the newest version of [gradle](https://gradle.org/releases)
- Go to `Preferences > External Tools > Android` and de-select `Gradle installed with Unity`. Enter the path you installed gradle in previous step
- Enable `Player Settings > Publishing Settings > Build > Custom Base Gradle Template`
- Go to custom template (`Assets/Plugins/Android/baseProjectTemplate.gradle` by default) and change plugin version to `3.5.0`. Note that `3.6+` versions have other bugs so I found that `3.5.0` works the best. It should look like this: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I hope it will be helpful for some people. I fixed my problem changing the OS Language. It was quite challenging tho. I reinstalled Windows 10 Home Single Language with the media creation tool. Then I was able to change system language.